# How to fix error Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: errors

I know this must be a common title for a question, and I have done my research but I still can't figure out why i get this error with this block of code:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{1.2pt}
\setlength{\lightrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{UMAP 2017 Short Paper}
\rhead{UMAP’17, July 9-12, 2017, Bratislava, Slovakia}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{}
\newfont{\mycrnotice}{ptmr8t at 7pt}
\newfont{\myconfname}{ptmri8t at 7pt}
\let\crnotice\mycrnotice
\let\confname\myconfname

\begin{document}
\title{Improving Cold Start Recommendation by Mapping
        Feature-Based Preferences to Item Comparisons}

\numberofauthors{2}

\author{
\alignauthor
Saikishore Kalloori\\
       \affaddr{Free University of Bozen - Bolzano,}\\
       \affaddr{Piazza Domenicani 3, I - 39100,}\\
       \email{ksaikishore@unibz.it}
\alignauthor
Francesco Ricci\\
       \affaddr{Free University of Bozen - Bolzano,}\\
       \affaddr{Piazza Domenicani 3, I - 39100,}\\
       \email{fricci@unibz.it}
}
\maketitle
\section{EXPERIMENTAL EVALUATION}\noindent
\subsection{Data Set}\noindent
In order to test our hypothesis we needed a dataset containing both
item and feature preferences. The only publicly available data set
with such preferences, which we could identify, is the PoliMovie
dataset \cite{10}. For each user in the dataset, there are preferences
expressed explicitly for movies and for their features, in the form
of likes.
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{zdroje}
\end{document}
```

Error is pointed to the first line with \section. It says:

Missing number, treated as zero. Overfull \hbox(1.82866 pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 140--154.

Link to sig-alternate and my .bib file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hg5Rw9iFLI1w6hSyAwlRyX29bkMwyIXY

I have couple of errors like this scattered throughout the whole document near \section commands. I see only couple of lines highlighted with this error(no other kinds of errors appear) but overleaf says that I have 37 errors, even though the document compiles OK, and looks just like it's supposed to look.
Any ideas how to fix this error? Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please post a full minimal example instead of just a sniplet. This can be caused by all sorts of things, but without a proper context example the others can just copy and test as is, it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: It's quite unlikely that the code above issues a “Missing number” error, unless you have redefined `\section` (possibly via packages). Thus a minimal example is needed. By the way, `\noindent` is redundant and you should remove it.

Comment: You should never trust the output if you got errors, even if it looks sort of OK. Unfortunately, the error you got is very generic and can be caused by many different things. The code shown in the question looks OK-ish w.r.t. the error (I'd not write `\section{RELATED WORK}`, instead I'd tell the class to format sections in ALL CAPS, of that is desired; I would also not use `\noindent`, if it is necessary at all - which is not clear - it could instead be done automatically; I would not use numeric-labels as bibkeys, I would use recognisable names such as `sigfridsson` or `liggett:ips`). ...

Comment: ... So the error can only be properly diagnosed if you tell us more about the context of that code. This is best done by creating a minimal example (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) a short, but complete document with `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` that reproduces the message you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you @daleif , I edited the post added full minimal example.

Comment: @moewe unfortunatelly I am supposed to recreate someone elses document and stuff like numeric-labels as bibkeys are required.

Comment: OK, if you say so. Where can we find `sig-alternate`? We also don't have `zdroje.bib`, so we can't run your exact code, but we may be able to see the error without that file.

Comment: @moewe I added link to sig alternate and my .bib file, sig alternate is only a template file, and .bib is a collection of all my references, in the code snippet i just excluded \bibliographystyle{abbrv} and \bibliography{zdroje} commands that are before the end of document.

Comment: The error goes away if I remove the `\pagestyle{fancy}` line. In the example I could not detect a difference, but that may be different in your real document. I'm not a `fancyhdr` user, so I don't really know what exactly would be the best course of action.

Comment: `\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}` is the correct command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was posted by user @egreg, I just needed to change commands:

```
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{}
```

to:

```
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

The issue was connected with package fancyhdr,as user @moewe pointed out.
Thank you all for your help.